# Using FS module to insert content into objects

Tags: javascript, fs

Hello i am trying to use FS module to read an external .txt file.It reads line by line, but i want it to create a new object and store the content in this.word and this.definition.Finally, I want to store all the objects into an array, I have tried several methods but i can't seem to figure it out.

This is a demo txt file(take \n as next line i do not know how to display next line here):

triangle\n
a plane figure with three straight sides and three angles.\n
square\n
a plane figure with four equal straight sides and four right angles.\n

The code is :

```
var arr = [];

class Word {
    constructor(word, definition) {
        this.word = word;
        this.definition = definition;
    } 
}

const fs = require('fs');

try {
    // read contents of the file
    const data = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'UTF-8');

    // split the contents by new line
    const lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);

    lines.forEach((line) => {
        
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a module line-reader help reading file line by line:

```
const lineReader = require('line-reader');

let i = 1;
lineReader.eachLine('file.txt', function (line) {
  console.log('line:', i);
  console.log(line);
  i = i + 1;
});
```

You should describe more about class Word and how you want to store data into this class (what is this.word, this.definition).

**Noted**: We should not read the whole file with fs.readFileSync because it can cause your memory overload, and the speed is slow.